# How do I loop a HTML name value with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a PHP page pulls mobile phones from a database. Depending on how many phones are in the database, the PHP page will determine how many fields to create. I have a session in place to only allow those who are logged in, able to edit and access certain features.

I want the checkbox to update the database with a 1 (as active) and a 0 (as inactive) devices so I will be able to show only those which are active.

Edit: session_start(); is in every page within header.php connected to the top of each page. I have left that out in the code.

**phones.php**

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_SESSION['u_name'])) {
        echo ' <button type="submit" name="submit" 
        form="activeForm">Save</button>';
    }
    for($x = 1; $x <= deviceCount("phones"); $x++) { 
?>
    </section>
        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['u_name'])) {
        ?>  
        <form id="activeForm" method="POST" action="save.php">
            <input type="checkbox" echo ' name="active'.$x.'"';?>>
        </form>
    <?php 
        } 
    } 
    ?>
```

Below is my PHP. I am wanting to check if each check box is selected. The issue I am having is that after the first checkbox is checked, the rest are always not selected.

**save.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include_once 'connect.inc.php';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM phones";
    if ($result=mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
        // Return the number of rows in result set
        $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    }

    for($x = 1; $x < $rowcount + 1; $x++) {
        $select = 'active'.$x;
        if (isset($_POST[$select])) {
            $sql = "UPDATE phones SET active='1' WHERE id=$x";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        } else {
            $sql = "UPDATE phones SET active='0' WHERE id=$x";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say I have 4 devices. The first checkbox would be responsive, however, the next 3 would all say not selected.

Comment: your button is above than form and each check-box have it's own form. so i am unable to understand how's your form is submitted, and of-course if it submitted any-how then also only single-checkbox data will be submit

Comment: you can set the name into an array and make the value dependent on the mobile number. Also your form is inside your loop. It should be outside while the checkboxes is inside the loop

Comment: <input type="checkbox"  name="active<?= $x ?>" > i found error in your code phone.php

Comment: you have to put submit button in between your form tag because you check submit in your save.php file and you need write <form> outside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You need to put form code outside of the loop.

2.Use input name as array-type

3.You need to have `session_start();`

4.Based on array-type name change php code accordingly.

Do like below:-

***HTML:-***

```
<form id="activeForm" method="POST" action="save.php"> 
<?php
    session_start();//needed
    if (isset($_SESSION['u_name'])) {
        for($x = 1; $x <= deviceCount("phones"); $x++) { 
?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="active[<?php echo $x;?>]" />   
<?php 
        } 
    } 
?>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

***PHP:-***

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include_once 'connect.inc.php';
    foreach($_POST['active'] as $key =>$x) {
        if ($x) {
            $sql = "UPDATE phones SET active='1' WHERE id=$key";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        } else {
            $sql = "UPDATE phones SET active='0' WHERE id=$key";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I left out header.php. A session_start(); occurs with every page in the header.

Comment: Ok, then `session_start();` is not needed again. Use rest of the code and check

Comment: God bless! You made my night. Thank you so much!

Comment: @TyJ glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

**phones.php**

```
  <?php 
// you need first start session
 session_start();

        if (isset($_SESSION['u_name'])) {
            echo ' <button type="submit" name="submit" 
            form="activeForm">Save</button>';
        }
        for($x = 1; $x <= deviceCount("phones"); $x++) { 
    ?>
        </section>
            <?php
                if (isset($_SESSION['u_name'])) {
            ?>  
            <form id="activeForm" method="POST" action="save.php">
                <input type="checkbox"  name="active<?= $x ?>" >
            </form>
        <?php 
            } 
        } 
        ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I left out header.php. A session_start(); occurs with every page in the header.

Comment: i had mention your code have some error in  <input type="checkbox" echo ' name="active'.$x.'"';?>>